# Finding the balance point in an array

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, data-structures

This question is from a great youtube channel, giving problems that can be asked in interviews.

It's basically related to finding the balance point in an array. Here is an example to best explain it;
{1,2,9,4,-1}. In here since sum(1+2)=sum(4+(-1)) making the 9 the **balance point**. Without checking the answer I've decided to implement the algorithm before wanted to ask whether a more efficient approach could be done;

1. Sum all the elements in array **O(n)**
2. Get the half of the sum **O(1)**
3. Start scanning the array, from left, and stop when the **sumleft** is bigger than half of the general sum. **O(n)**
4. Do the same for the right, to obtain **sum right.** **O(n)**.
5. If **sumleft** is equal to **sumright** return **arr[size/2]** else return **-1**

I'm asking because this solution popped into my head without any effort, providing the O(n) running time. Is this solution, if true, could be developed or if not true any alternative methods?

Comment: What if there's no balance point, like  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}?

Comment: @jrok I think the balance point of that array is the `4`. IE the sum of the elements to the left is `6` the sum of the elements to the `right` is `5`. The distance we want to minimize is only `1`. The trick is in the fact that the array can contain negative numbers.

Comment: @jrok - your example DOES have a balance point, it just isnt an integer placement within the set.  It is balanced at some point between the 4 and 5.

Comment: What happens when there is more than one balance point? (e.g. `1 0 1 -1 0 1` , both `0`s are balance points)

Answer (score 6):

Your algorithm is not good (counter-example: `1 -1 1 0 1 -1 1`), the good solution is to compute partial sum of your array (so that you can can compute `sumleft` and `sumright` in O(1) for each cell of the array) and then (or in the same time if you already know the global sum) search in your array a cell such that `sumleft = sumright` which is O(n).

The partial sum of the array `A` is

```
[A[0], A[0]+A[1], A[0]+A[1]+A[2], …, A[0]+A[1]+A[2]+…+A[n-1]]
```

example:

```
A=[5,2,3,1,4,6]
partial sum = [5,7,10,11,15,21]
```

With this array you can compute `sumleft[i]=partial_sum[i-1]` and `sumright[i]=partial_sum[n-1]-partial_sum[i]`

Improvement:

Computing the global sum first and then only the partial sum for the current index enable you to use only O(1) extra space instead of O(n) extra space if you store all the partial_sum array.

Comment: Thanks for the counter-example! Was really looking forward to it. Can you explain this method in detail. I could not follow what you meant by partial sum

Comment: I was examining your example and noticed that does this example have a balance point?

Comment: You might wanna define sumleft[i] = sum[i-1] and sumright[i] = sum[n-1] - sum[i]. That would give a complete solution.

Comment: @lcfseth indeed, I thought it was obvious.

Comment: I would vote you up if your answer were a bit more complete -- you shouldn't assume anything is "obvious"!

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide more explanations and an new improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually have 2 start points, one on the leftmost point (leftLoc), and one at the right most point (rightLoc).  Hold a sumLeft and sumRight numbers.

```
leftLoc  = 0;
rightLoc = (n - 1);
sumRight = array[rightLoc];
sumLeft  = array[leftLoc];

while(leftLoc < rightLoc){
    if(sumRight > sumLeft){
        leftLoc++;
        sumLeft += array[leftLoc];
    }else{
        rightLoc--;
        sumRight += array[rightLoc];
    } 
}

if( (sumRight + array[rightLoc - 1]) == sumLeft ){
    return rightLoc--;
}else if( (sumLeft + array[leftLoc + 1]) == sumRight){
    return leftLoc++;
}else{
    // return floating point number location in the middle of the 2 locations
}
```

All the while keeping track of how many total positions have been moved O(n)

You may find that your balance point is a floating point number in the middle of the final points (once they are at the integer locations right next to one another).

This **should** even work with the negative numbers example.  Perhaps I am missing some fine grain details, but some variation on this theme should result you in an O(n) runtime algorithm.

Comment: I guess you do this procedure in a loop like 'while(leftmost<rightmost)' right?

Comment: counter-example: `1 -1 1 0 -1 1 -1`

Comment: @Thomash - My algorithm still works, the answer is "somewhere between the leftmost 1, and -1", try it, I did, and it works.  In this case the answer will be exactly half way between the above forementioned points.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to write `1 -1 1 0 1 -1 1`.

Comment: Yes, I did state that there might be a special case, in this case, one could solve this by checking if the last movement would indeed result in a 0 difference.  I will try to edit my algorithm to show this!!!

Comment: Apologies for making this TOO code looking, but it does get the point across.  This will result in a TRUE O(n) algo.

Comment: First, I don't get what you mean by TRUE O(n). If you do it in two linear passes, it's still O(n), end of discussion. Second, your algorithm implicitly assumes that all numbers are positive, which is not true. For instance `-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 5`

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem properly. The correct balance point for that case would be the second -1, quite far away from the 5.

Comment: @ffao - I see your point!  however the else routine would look (something like) this.  PosToMove = (sumRight - sumLeft) / 2, which in this case would be 13 / 2 = 6.  If you move the 6 positions left of the current leftLoc, then you would end at the position you stated.  Like I stated, I didn't purposefully put what belongs in the else clause, but an averaging approach would land at the same position.  I apologize, I mis-spoke when I said it landed to the right of the 5.  Regardless thanks for the notes.  I will try to add my else clause portion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically add up all the numbers first. This will be an O(n) operation. Then substract one element from the array at a time starting from the beginning of the array till `upper` == `lower`. Thus the total order will be O(n).

```
int BalancePoint(int a[], int begin, int end) // find index of an array (balance point) such that sum of all elements before the index = sum of all elements after it; else return -1
{
    if(!a) return -1;
    else if(begin == end) return begin;

        long long upper = 0;
        long long lower = 0;

    for(int i = begin; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        upper += *(a+i);
    }

    for(int j = begin; j <= end; ++j)
    {
        upper -= *(a+j);
        if(upper == lower) return j;
        lower += *(a+j);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Using STL

```
int BalancePointSTL( const vector<int> &A ) // find index of an array (balance point) such that sum of all elements before the index = sum of all elements after it; else return -1
{
    if(A.empty()) return -1;

        long long upper = 0;
        long long lower = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= A.size(); ++i)
    {
        upper += A[i];
    }

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < A.size(); ++j)
    {
        upper -= A[j];
        if(upper == lower) return j;
        lower += A[j];
    }
    return -1;
    }
```

The following would have a better worst case performance but a couple more `if-else` comparisons

```
int BalancePoint2(int a[], int begin, int end) // Better worst case senario by factor of 2
{
    if(!a) return -1;
    else if(begin == end) return begin;

        long long upper = 0;
        long long lower = 0;

        int mid = (end-begin)/2;

        for(int i = begin; i < mid; ++i)
        {
            lower += *(a+i);
        }
        for(int i = mid+1; i <= end; ++i)
        {
            upper += *(a+i);
        } 

        if(upper == lower) return mid;
        else if(lower < upper)
        {
            lower += *(a+mid);
            for(int i= mid + 1 ; i <= end ; ++i)
            {
                upper -= *(a + i);
                if(upper == lower) return i;
                lower += *(a + i);
            }
        }
        else {
            upper += *(a + mid);
            for(int i = mid - 1; i >=begin; --i)
            {
                lower -= *(a + i);
                if(upper == lower) return i;
                upper += *(a + i);
            }
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I'm not really looking for a code. But thanks again

Comment: I found the best approach to be adding all the numbers first and assigning teh value to a variable called say `upper`. Then set the `balance point` as the first variable from the input array while substracting its value from `upper`. Set another variable `lower` to 0. This is your starting point. Then move the `balance point` along the array one element at a time while adding that element to `lower` and substracting it from `upper`. Do this till `upper == lower`. If you come to the end of the array without meeting that balance condition, return saying balance point does not exist.

Comment: This is the SLOW way of doing it!!! You dont need a full sum first. Indeed these are good coding samples, but not the fastest implementations.  He was looking for BETTER, not the SAME.  You have implemented the same as what his question essentially states

Comment: This is slower but worked for all cases including when negative numbers can cause the lower sum to be higher than the upper sum before reaching balance point. Like in Thomash's example `{1 -1 1 0 1 -1 1}`. Also my scheme will find only the first balance point in an input array like `{1 -1 1 0 0 0 1 -1 1}`.

Comment: `std::accumulate` would take a few lines out.

Comment: @chris - That's true. But according to [this page on `std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/) its using a while loop. So I thought it would be better to just implement the loop myself than calling a functor which also employs a similar loop. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @ChinmayNerurkar, You should almost always prefer pre-made things to making your own. It's more versatile, less typing, usually faster than what you make, heavily tested to be bug-free already, and immediately clear from the name what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the *centroid* or *center of mass*. In pure Python:

```
def centroid(input_list):
    idx_val_sum = 0.0
    val_sum = 0.0
    for idx,val in enumerate(input_list):
        idx_val_sum += idx*val
        val_sum += val
    return idx_val_sum/float(val_sum)
```

It's **O(n)** and if non-integer results are ill-formed, you can reject them with a modulo check:

```
def integer_centroid(input_list):
    idx_val_sum = 0.0
    val_sum = 0.0
    for idx,val in enumerate(input_list):
        idx_val_sum += idx*val
        val_sum += val
    out = idx_val_sum/float(val_sum)
    if out%1.0==0.0:
        return out
    else:
        raise ValueError("Input list has non-integer centorid.")
```

This post should have been a comment replying to trumpetlicks June 14 2012 comment, but I don't have enough reputation. "Order" is implicitly tracked in `idx_val_sum`, which is the cumulative position sum weighted by value.

**Edit:**

Matt, thank you for your observation. I assumed this was a pseudocode question, but now I see the C++ tag. Here's some (untested) C++, with comments.

An intuitive example is a simple lever arm problem: if you have a lever with two forces *f1* and *f2* acting on it at positions *x1* and *x2*, you can prevent the system from rotating by applying a force at position *(f1*x1+f2*x2)/(f1+f2)*. A continuous system requires integration over the product of *x* and *f*, but levers with discrete locations and forces are a good analogy for this problem.

```
// untested code:

float centroid(float * vec, int vec_length){

  float idx_val_sum = 0.0;
  float val_sum = 0.0;

  for (idx = 0; idx < vec_length; idx++){

    // keep a running sum of the product of the index and the value
    idx_val_sum += float(idx)*vec[idx];

    // similarly, keep a running sum of the index
    val_sum += vec[idx];

  }
  // return the quotient of the product-sum and the index sum:
  return idx_val_sum/val_sum;
}
```

Comment: This is a C++ question ; it'd be helpful if you explained your algorithm so that people who don't know Python can follow your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that's O(n) and doesn't require more space

```
def balance_array(arr):
    if len(arr) < 3:
        return False

    for i in range(1, len(arr)+1):
        lsum = sum(arr[:i])
        rsum = sum(arr[(i+1):])
        if lsum == rsum:
            return True
    return False
```

Testing

`test_arrays = [[5, 3, 7, 0, 9], [5,2,3,1,4,6], [1,0,1], [1,6,5,1,2,3,1], [1,1], [], [1], [1,2,9,4,-1], [5, 4, 7, 0, 9], [1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1]]`

```
for i in test_arrays:
    print(f'{i}\t{balance_array(i)}')

[5, 3, 7, 0, 9]         False
[5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6]      True
[1, 0, 1]               True
[1, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1]   True
[1, 1]                  False
[]                      False
[1]                     False
[1, 2, 9, 4, -1]        True
[5, 4, 7, 0, 9]         True
[1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1] True
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for the [Center of Mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass), here is a solution written in Go:

```
func centerOfGravity(a []int) float64 {
  tot := 0.0
  mass := 0.0
  for i := range a {
    tot += float64(i) * float64(a[i])
    mass += float64(a[i])
  }
  return tot / mass
}
```

This gives you the index of the center of mass in the array, assuming a 0-based array.  It can return a non-integer result since the center of mass can be anywhere in the range of the array.

Comment: This is TOTALLY useless, center of mass doesn't care about order, this answer needs to care about the order.  How does center of mass return indexed position in this case?